# JQuery in Dynamically loaded UserControl

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically loading a user control on a click of a checkbox. I need to run a post on the Jquery when a button is clicked on the user control. When I Load my User Control, I cannot run

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     alert('I am here!!');
});  as a test.
```

Any Ideas. or do I need a $.getScript() ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the code in the callback of the load method.

```
$('#content').ajax({
     url: '/some/url',
     ...
     success: function(data) {
         $('#content').html( data.Html ); // assumes JSON with Html parameter
         $('#content').find('input[type=submit]').click( function() {
             ...do your submit...
             return false; // cancel default action
         }),
     ...
});
```

Or, perhaps -- depending on the situation -- set it up with a live handler.

```
$('#content').find('input[type=submit]').live('click', function() {
    ... do your submit...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I am unable to run that, I am dynamically loading the User control.

Comment: I am loading User COntrol using 
http://weblogs.asp.net/sanjeevagarwal/archive/2008/07/29/Dynamically-create-ASP.NET-user-control-using-JQuery-and-JSON-enabled-Ajax-Web-Service.aspx

Comment: Looks like you are using AJAX/JSON instead of load.  In that case, put the code in the success callback.  Will update.

Comment: Can we run multiple functions in Success; ex dump the htnl in the div and attach the click event for  the buton in the user control.

Comment: Yes.  It's just a function that will be executed after the AJAX call has returned.  I omitted the data parameter to it, but I'll update.